# How to communicate between a PHP and a C++ application through a socket?

Tags: php, c++, sockets, ipc

How do I send a message from a PHP-client to a C-server using a socket.
I need simple code, one TCP-connection.

The client is written in PHP and the server in C on Windows.

Comment: What have you done so far? There are many many C socket tutorials on the internet

Comment: C or C++? It's OK to have vague questions, but you should put enough effort into thinking about your problem to agree on the *language* you want to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Communication with C++ Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021029/php-communication-with-c-application)

Comment: It is C++ . I saw some example in C. I saw some examples in php. I dont know to connect them

Comment: is it C or C++ or any of them? can you edit your question/title to avoid confusion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789720/communicate-c-program-and-php/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261364/what-is-a-good-inter-process-communication-method-between-c-and-php-in-linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746207/how-to-ipc-between-php-clients-and-a-c-daemon-server

Answer (score 0):

See at first example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php).

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);  //AF_UNIX - it's important!
$socket_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/socket_file.sock';
socket_bind($socket, $socket_file);
socket_recvfrom($socket, $some_buf, $input_buf_size, 0, $from);
socket_sendto($socket, $some_buf, $some_buf_len, 0, $from);
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).