# using named pipes to communicate c++/php on Windows

Tags: php, c++, named-pipes

I want to use a pipe to send data from a php web application to a c++ running program.
I am not sure of what is exactly a pipe and how to use it, and most of the documentation I find is for unix machines but I am working locally on Windows...

Here are my simple questions :

- what exactly is a pipe ? if I write my data into a file from my web app and that data is read by the c++ program, is that a pipe ?
- How can I create it from php on Windows ? (without posix)
- How can I read this data from my program

currently what I would do is surely pretty bad :

**c++**

```
while(true){
  ifstream infile("test.txt");

  if (infile.good())
  {
    string sLine;
    getline(infile, sLine);
    // do some stuff
  }

  infile.close();
}
```

**php :**

```
<?php    
    $resPipe = fopen("myfile", "w");
    fwrite($resPipe, "foo");
    fclose($resPipe);
?>
```

Comment: See if this helps : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021029/php-communication-with-c-application

You'll basically want some socket listeners on both ends(or at least in C++ as the receiver).

Comment: If you don't know what a name pipe is, why do you assume, that it will solve your problem? At any rate, named pipes for Windows are documented at [Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590.aspx). Yes, this implies potentially reading a lot.

Comment: Your php approach is misleading. You are trying to open a file in the local file system. Such file can be used for inter process communication, but AFAIK only on unix like systems. What you are looking for instead are sockets. http://php.net/manual/de/book.sockets.php

Comment: You were right, sockets is what was the best option in my case. Thanks!
If anyone has any trouble using sockets on windows (because of `"sys/socket.h"` that does not exists, take a look at that (for c++): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , and at that (for php) : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP